# How to change space between (sub)section number and title in memoir class?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, formatting, memoir

I am required to have **exactly** one space between chapter/section/subsection/etc. number and title in my document.

I am using memoir class (also a requirement).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `memoir` the default is to have **Chapter 1** on one line and then **Title** on a second line; there is no `space' between the number and title. If you are using a non-default chapter style you should say so.

For lower level headings there is a quad space (`\quad`) between the number and title. Use the `\setsecnumformat` to change this.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname\space}% change the spacing
\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\end{document}
```

See the section *Lower level headings* in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) for more information.